Problem about creating a Windows installation of a project written in Flutter
I have developed an application in Flutter and I want to be able to install it on computers with different windows operating systems.
I create a setup through the “Inno Setup Compiler” application. When I install the setup file, my application is installed, but when I click “Open”, the application does not open. I don't get any error. My application runs smoothly in debug mode on Visual Code. Waiting for your support.
My iss codes for Inno Setup Compiler:
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.1"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "https://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "productionapp.exe"
#define MyAppAssocName MyAppName + " File"
#define MyAppAssocExt ".myp"
#define MyAppAssocKey StringChange(MyAppAssocName, " ", "") + MyAppAssocExt

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{E08A8A6C-7CCA-4623-8DB1-A708C15B30D5}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppName}
; "ArchitecturesAllowed=x64compatible" specifies that Setup cannot run
; on anything but x64 and Windows 11 on Arm.
ArchitecturesAllowed=x64compatible
; "ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64compatible" requests that the
; install be done in "64-bit mode" on x64 or Windows 11 on Arm,
; meaning it should use the native 64-bit Program Files directory and
; the 64-bit view of the registry.
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64compatible
ChangesAssociations=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=C:\Users\berkhan.akdag\Desktop\My Setups
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "turkish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Turkish.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\berkhan.akdag\productionapp\build\windows\x64\runner\Release\{#MyAppExeName}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\berkhan.akdag\productionapp\build\windows\x64\runner\Release\productionapp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\berkhan.akdag\productionapp\build\windows\x64\runner\Release\file_selector_windows_plugin.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\berkhan.akdag\productionapp\build\windows\x64\runner\Release\flutter_windows.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\berkhan.akdag\productionapp\build\windows\x64\runner\Release\data\flutter_assets\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Registry]
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocExt}\OpenWithProgids"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{#MyAppAssocKey}"; ValueData: ""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{#MyAppAssocName}"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},0"
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocKey}\shell\open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: """{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"" ""%1"""
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\Applications\{#MyAppExeName}\SupportedTypes"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ".myp"; ValueData: ""

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent



